# Copy text from HTML that is other than the text there

Tags: html, css

I have some text on a web page referring to LaTeX, the formatter.  In the HTML source the text is this.

```
<span class="latex">L<sup>a</sup>T<sub>e</sub>X</span>
```

(Snippet is below including CSS.)  When a user copies it, they get "LATEX", all caps.  I would like them to get "LaTeX", which is the preferred spelling.  Is there a (cross-browser) way to do that?

```css
.tex sub,
.latex sub,
.latex sup {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0;
}
.tex sub,
.latex sub {
  vertical-align: -0.5ex;
  margin-left: -0.1667em;
  margin-right: -0.125em;
  line-height: 0;
}
.tex,
.latex,
.tex sub,
.latex sub {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 0;
}
.latex sup {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  vertical-align: 0.15em;
  margin-left: -0.36em;
  margin-right: -0.15em;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
 <span class="latex">L<sup>a</sup>T<sub>e</sub>X</span>
```

Comment: when i copy/paste from the snippet here is what i paste: LaTeX . Maybe i misunderstand the question.

Comment: When I copy the text on http://joshua.smcvt.edu/latexmath/ it comes out as LATEX.  (Ubuntu 14.04, Firefox)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/copy-paste-the-web/#article-header-id-10

Comment: @Pangloss Yes I saw that page when I googled.  I want a cross-browser way to get the LaTeX in the Copy-Paste, and LATEX (with sub-bing and super-ing) in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the

```
.tex sub, .latex sub, .latex sup {
  text-transform: uppercase;line-height: 0;
  }
```

To

```
.tex sub, .latex sub, .latex sup {
   line-height: 0;
  }
```

`text-tranform` is making the text uppercase

Comment: Thank you.  If I don't transform them to uppercase, or enter them as uppercase, then the LaTeX logo does not come out correct.  It requires that the letters appear in upper case.

Comment: Are you trying to have CSS do all the case changes?

Comment: I am trying to get LATEX, with sub-bing and super-ing, in the browser and LaTeX in the copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a duplicate of the text with the original case "LaTeX", and wrap it into a span, set the `color` to `transparent` or `rgba(0,0,0,0)`, and `user-select: all;` plus some position tricks, this is for copy & paste. Then set the other span to `user-select: none;` for display.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.duplicate {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: transparent;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  -webkit-user-select: all;
  -moz-user-select: all;
  -ms-user-select: all;
  user-select: all;
}

.latex {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.tex sub,
.latex sub,
.latex sup {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0;
}

.tex sub,
.latex sub {
  vertical-align: -0.5ex;
  margin-left: -0.1667em;
  margin-right: -0.125em;
  line-height: 0;
}

.tex,
.latex,
.tex sub,
.latex sub {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 0;
}

.latex sup {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  vertical-align: 0.15em;
  margin-left: -0.36em;
  margin-right: -0.15em;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
This is the
<div class="container">
  <span class="latex">L<sup>a</sup>T<sub>e</sub>X</span>
  <span class="duplicate">LaTeX</span>
</div>
logo.
```

Comment: Thank you; what a clever idea.  I find that (1) if I say "This is <insert the div here> for you." then there is a linbreak between the "is" and the "LaTeX."  (2) I also find that it copies as  "This is<linebreak> LATEX LaTeX for you."  (Ubuntu 14, Chrome)

Comment: @JimHefferon The answer solves your original question, I'd suggest you to post a new question if you need further help, be sure to make a clear demo, so more people and help.

Comment: I don't find that to be so; do I have it all wrong?  I put the code in https://jsfiddle.net/jimhefferon/tktt2qdn/1/.  I find that copying from mozilla gives me linebreaks before and after "LaTeX" while copying from Chrome gives me "LATEX LaTeX  ".  Thank you, though.

Comment: @JimHefferon I updated it added `user-select: all;` to the other span, now it should work https://jsfiddle.net/tktt2qdn/2/ let me know.

Comment: I really cannot thank you enough. I hope I can help you back in some way some day.  I don't see that the change had any effect when I updated the jsfiddle.  But I am afraid I have taken too much of your time; let's call it not-doable.

Comment: @JimHefferon No worries. I don't have ubuntu to test it but the newly updated code works fine on both chrome and firefox on the mac.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS [text-transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp) Property

```
p.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

p.lowercase {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To leapfrog off Boris' reply, what I would do is create the following css:

```
.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.lowercase {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Then for your code, use

```
<span class="uppercase">L</span><span class="lowercase">a</span><span class="uppercase">T</span><span class="lowercase">e</span><span class="uppercase">X</span>
```

The capitalization in your code won't matter since CSS is changing the case for you.